# Creating a custom VSTS-Task

Tags: azure-pipelines-build-task

I am developing a VSTS task and I am having problems with references to different modules.

My first question: When building a task, you need to add the VstsTaskSDK. Do I need to this by copying the module into the  TaskRoot/ps_modules? Or is there a certain flag when building the task that can this?
If I need to copy it in the root, how am I going to handle multiple tasks? Copy it in the root of every task? Is there a neater way to do this? Store the sdk in one place and copy it somehow?

I have used the https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks repo for samples and noticed that shared code is available in "Tasks/Common". Where are the manifest files? I also would like to have a common folder and would like to be able to reference (and copy in the task-package on build), any ideas how?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using [VSTS DevOps Task SDK](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-task-lib). The SDK should be packaged with the task in a `ps_modules` folder. The `ps_modules` folder should be in the root of the task folder.

Example layout: Consider the following layout where MyTask is the root folder for the task.

```
MyTask
|   MyTask.ps1
│   task.json
└───ps_modules
    └───VstsTaskSdk
            [...]
            VstsTaskSdk.psd1
```

Instead of "Tasks/Common", you can use [MSBuild Task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/MSBuild) as an example. More information about manifest files, please refer to [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/manifest).